# Is there a way to make transfer money to debicart with zero balance in stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i have made transfer to debit card api for stripe and works fine but is there any way to transfer with zero balance in  stripe account  ?

i have added the bank account in stripe ,so they will cut money automatic from my account ?

Comment: Its hard to understand your question. Stripe won't transfer funds to you if you don't have any money to transfer.

Comment: if i had zero balance and make stripe create transfer stripe will do negative balance ?

if i had zero balance in stripe and making transfer to debit card for $1 then stripe will make -$1 i.e. negative balance ?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's API will error if you try to create a transfer to your bank account without there being any money to transfer. From their API docs:

> To send funds from your Stripe account to a third-party recipient or
> to your own bank account, you create a new transfer object. **Your
> Stripe balance must be able to cover the transfer amount, or you'll
> receive an "Insufficient Funds" error**.
>
> If your API key is in test
> mode, money won't actually be sent, though everything else will occur
> as if in live mode.

Comment: yes i know that error,i want to prevent that that's why asking for negative balance.

Comment: There is no way to get more money out of Stripe than what is in there. That's what Stripe's documentation is telling you.